# Is there a way to get a category's name in lowercase?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories, permalinks

I am setting up a Wordpress theme and I'm integrating a facebook "Like" button into each of the categories.

I need a way of getting the current page URL in lowercase so I can have several like buttons for all the categories while each having different url links.

Currently, when I use `<?php get_permalink( ); ?>` or `<?php the_permalink( ); ?>` in the category template, it outputs the URL plus the permalink of the first post, which isn't what I want currently.

I've tried using  but it outputs the title with the first letter Capped. I need the category name in lowercase for the URL to be valid in order to link each category page to facebook.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

Answer (score 1):

add a style attribute for it:

```
text-transform:lowercase
```

Comment: Using css would change the presentation, but the underlying text would remain capitalised.