# Make PHP result all lowercase letters

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get a category's name in lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289325/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-categorys-name-in-lowercase)

This code currently grabs actor data from the MYSQL and then prints it out.

Is there a way to edit the below code so that the a href link result is all lowercase letters?

```
$TMPL['actor'] = '';
    foreach(explode(', ', $TMPL['actors']) as $v)
    $TMPL['actor'] .= '<a href="/actor/'.str_replace("+", "-", urlencode($v)). '">'.$v.'</a> <br />';       
    $actors .= $skin->make();
```

Comment: title of question does not match body. pick one!

Comment: contardiction in ur question ...

Comment: I do apologize! changed.

Comment: [strtolower()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) not hard to find. please search first next time.

Comment: When you run into stuff like this, first try searching the php docs.  It is suuuper easy to do.  You can search for uppercase by going to:  http://php.net/uppercase which would find you the function in the answer below.

Comment: -1. We expect some research to be done, the least of which is looking it up in the manual!

Comment: Echoing everyone else here... if you had typed your title into google you would have gotten your answer (for me, the first result was http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$TMPL['actor'] = '';
    foreach(explode(', ', $TMPL['actors']) as $v)
    $TMPL['actor'] .= '<a href="/actor/'.strtolower(str_replace("+", "-", urlencode($v))). '">'.$v.'</a> <br />';       
    $actors .= $skin->make();
```

Using php's [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/strtolower).

There is also [`strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

Answer (score 0):

`strtoupper(string $str)` — Make a string uppercase

`strtolower(string $str)` — Make a string lowercase